# json encode error when adding a new column in sql

Tags: mysql, json

I have a query:

```
"SELECT Time, Date, Name, Email FROM table"
```

It converts the results to json to be passed via ajax, the problem is I want a new column in the sql, so I add it to the query:

```
"SELECT Time, Date, Name, Email, Address FROM table"
```

now the json encode does not work, I have tried changing data types and using `UTF-8` however this did not work, none of the others are using `UTF-8` but still work anyway, Thanks.

This is my code to encode to json which does work until I add the new collumn from sql

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    $tempArray = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
            $tempArray = $row;
            array_push($myArray, $tempArray);
        }
    echo json_encode($myArray);
}
```

---

#### Solved

The problem was the last column i was trying to get was called "Show" for some reason sql does not like this, i renamed this column to "lol" (temporary) and it works!

Comment: show your code..no error in query or encode type

Comment: where is the JSON part code ?

Comment: Could you provide an error description?

Comment: sorry, i do not get any errors only no result

Comment: your code looks correct. **`echo`** one by one and checked where you wrong

Comment: There is no output in case query fails, you just check if it's successful - but what to do if it's not? You might have an SQL error without knowing. Also, you never attempted to debug by printing your array. You just assumed that json_encode doesn't work. Where did you check that you have any results in the first place?

Comment: I did not just assume, I have the json array printed out, it will print results as expected until I add the new column.

Comment: You will probably find that SHOW is a keyword and should be enclosed in back quotes when used as a column name.